# How do you output gedit input in R to the Rstudio workspace

Tags: r, rstudio, workspace, gedit, gwidgets

I am trying to develop a small widget where I can input a number into a dialog box and then save that number to my workspace for further use later, however I am new to R and am having trouble retrieving the text input after it is inputed into the widget. I have found some threads on how to pass the information from one widget to another but not back to the workspace. The only way I have got it to work is to run the code to the second last line and manually running the last line separately. Can anyone help me please???

```
# clearing workspace
rm(list = ls())

# Loading packages
library(gWidgets)
library(gWidgetstcltk)

# Setting up Widget
win=gwindow(title='Experiment setup',visible = TRUE)
grp_name <- ggroup(container = win)
okbut<-ggroup(container = win)
lbl_data_frame_name <- glabel(
  'Choose number of indexing variables: ',
  container = grp_name
)
#Asking user for input
obj<-gedit(container=grp_name,handler=function(h,..){
  print(as.integer(svalue(h$obj)))
  }, action = dispose(win))
#Attempt to return text from user input to workspace
textfromgedit=svalue(obj)
```

Comment: I suspect you may need to save this script as a file, e.g. `script.R`, then call the file with `source("script.R")`. Does that do the trick?

Comment: I think you are looking for `ginput`. This use of `gedit` with the `dispose(win)` action isn't right. If you want to clear the window during the handler, add it to the handler and save the value within the handler. For that you will need to assign into a different environment. This task is typically done with `<<-`.

Comment: Thanks Guys, I tried both. Using in another script did not output the input text as a variable to the workspace, ginput worked, however I was unable to embed the ginput window into the original container. I want to do this as this will eventually be a subset of input windows in one container. I thought by setting either the "parent" or "widget" option in ginput as the container (grp_name in this case) that it would embed the ginput, but it did not. Any ideas? Thanks for your help. Its much appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this help?

`library(gWidgets2)
results <- new.env()
win <- gwindow("Save number")
gp <- gformlayout(container=win)
gedit("", container=gp, label="Number of variables",
      coerce.with=as.numeric, handler=function(h,...) {
    results$values <- svalue(h$obj)
})`

Without some trick, assignment in the handler will assign in a scope that isn't visible to the rest of the program. In the above an environment is used for the assignment. The `<<-` assignment operator is also possible for this task.

I also used `gformlayout` to better organize your widgets. It is available with `gWidgets2`, which I'd recommend using instead of the older `gWidgets`.